# Custom .ics file in a workflow email

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-calendar

This question has been asked, but many of the answer links are dead. I need to create an .ics file from a Calendar list. I want to create an reusable email to be sent automatically via workflow any time someone registers for an event, and have within the email a link to the particular event that the user registered for and an .ics file to add it to their calendar. All the answers I've found seem to say that you need to specify the Item ID to create the .ics, like so:

https://**site url**/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List=**list ID**&CacheControl=1&ID=**ID**&Using=event.ics

Where the bold text is the information that you enter manually.

What I need is for the Item ID for the event to be pulled in automatically from the list, and inserted into the proper place to make an .ics file for that particular event. I thought maybe using "Current Item" lookup in the workflow email, but I'm not sure how to get the value returned to work with the above code. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workflow solves your problem to send an email to download the event file.

The syntax for the event file URL ias as follows

```
siteurl/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List={LIST GUID}&CacheControl=1&ID=itemid&Using=event.ics
```

**Get siteurl**

[image]

**Get LIST ID**

[image]

**Get Current Item ID**

[image]

Comment: beat me to it! great answer :)

Comment: Thank you! The first part worked fine. For some reason, "Workflow Context" doesn't give me an option for "List ID", and "Current Item" has no options at all. Is something wrong with my list? I'm pulling from an Events Calendar.

Comment: The List ID and ID are the default columns for every list. The above screenshots are from the workflow on a calendar list. It might be wrong with your list. You can create a test calendar list and see how it works.